# Can writing to logfiles seriously slow down your application?

Tags: performance, log4net

I'm using Log4Net to write logs to files. Can this serioulsy slow down my application? I know it depends on how much I'm writing away, but let's say that some hundreds of logs can be written per second.

Comment: Guaranteed it affects performance of your app. I would know, log4net file logging brought my app to a crawl. I was under the assumption file logging happened in a separate thread to avoid affecting the app - but nope! I've had the best luck logging to an API asynchronously like App insights. If you really wanted to log to a file, you could try doing what this guy did back in 2013 using Task or threadpool: https://www.ben-morris.com/using-asynchronous-log4net-appenders-for-high-performance-logging/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will slow down your application (obviously) but it depends a lot on your application if the slow down qualifies as "serious". I think you need to let it run and then decide if the performance is acceptable...

Answer (score 5):

Of course it *can*.

As you already said, it depends on how you write it.

If you are logging to a different hard-drive, things will be better. If you are logging via a message based transport, you will probably be OK.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can. It is crucial to consider the configuration, so you can configure it to not write that much log and then also not have much overhead.

eg.

```
if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
{
  logger.DebugFormat("log: {0}", myObject.ToString());
}
```

This will execute ToString only if needed.

The fact that you need to write the log to the disk when you enabled it - you can't do much against it. But usually it is not useful to write too much log, because nobody will ever read it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

"Slow" is not a binary property. It's relative to what else you're doing.

If whatever else you're doing takes 10 times as much wall-clock time as the logging, then logging will increase it by 10 *percent*: (10/10 + 1/10 = 1.1)

If whatever else you're doing takes 1/9 as much wall-clock time as the logging, then logging will increase it by 10 *times*: (1/1 + 9/1 = 10)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure regarding the slowness of application.

But i can say that if you are writing hundreds of logs per second and that too into a same file then make sure that thread synchronization is in place because you dont want crashes when multiple threads try to access same file.